# Group Policy - Only Apply to One Computer, and non-admins

Tags: group-policy

Where am I going wrong with the below?

We have a server running Server 2008 R2 which users connect to via remote desktop to run a CRM application.

This server has SQL Server 2012 installed, along with Management Studio.

Users in the Domain Admins group need access to management studio. 
Non-admin users should not be able to even open SQL management studio.

I have created an OU on the domain controller with this server (TSERVER) as the only object.
In this OU, I have created a group policy with ssms.exe in the list of disallowed applications.

In Delegation, I have Authenticated users set to Apply Group Policy, and for Domain Admins group, I have denied Apply Group Policy.

Even after running `gpupdate /force` on as the Administrator on TSERVER, the policy still doesn't apply, and users can still open SQL Management Studio.

I am pretty sure it's a basic setting I'm not applying.

Comment: Do you have the output of `gpresult` or tried to find errors with `rsop.msc`?

Comment: Using GPResult it shows under Denied GPOs, with Empty as the reason denied.

Comment: That is for a normal user, or a Domain Admin?

Comment: Under both Admin and regular user.

Comment: Weird... Try to delete the local cache of policies:
`del /S /F /Q "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Group Policy\History\*.*"`

Comment: Doh! I knew it would be something simple....
"User Group Policy loopback processing mode" Now enabled and set to Merge it works :)

Comment: Of course! :D Glad you find out!